# Any way to hide Disqus box from Tumblr ask page only?

Tags: tumblr, disqus

I have successfully added Disqus to my Tumblr page quite some time ago, but for consistency I would like to remove the Disqus box from the ask page or all static pages. Is that even possible?

One of my Tumblelogs can be found [here](http://i1984.net/) for reference.

Answer (score 6):

Found a way of doing it! Wrap it in PermalinkPagination blocks:

```
{block:PermalinkPagination}
   ...disqus code...
{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

PermalinkPagination only shows on posts (actually, it only shows on posts if they have a previous and/or a next post, so it won't work on blogs with only one post) and not static pages. You can use it within the context of a PermalinkPage block to include content that should only show on post pages rather than static pages.

You can use PermalinkPagination numerous times in the template.

To see it in action, have a look at [a static page](http://tommorris.org/) vs. [a blog post](http://blog.tommorris.org/post/4281259293/reading-fuller-on-the-draper-wright-conflict-model) on my Tumblr blog.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but that appears to break all the "x comments and y reactions" texts and links on the main "roll" page.

Comment: I'll pop the full template I'm using up shortly.

Comment: Thanks for that, Tom! But I still have a problem. Everything works fine in the blog posts and the disqus comments don't appear on the pages. But the "whatever-number comments" is still appearing on my pages and the ask page. I changed the HTML code on my page so the layout is the same but having a fixed content. But what can I do with the "ask" page? http://lodz-impressions.tumblr.com/ask I don't want "Comentarios" to appear anymore! :( Any idea? Thank you so much again! :)

Comment: Can you still provide the template?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this Tom. This place covers the exact same thing and provides an example. Might help others less familiar with coding: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/how-to-create-tumblr-theme/

Answer (score 5):

Wrapping the comment script in {block:Date} {/block:Date} seems to work, although it is a bit of a nasty hack. This works because {block:Date} is only rendered for posts with a date, which don't exist on the ask, submit, and static pages.

Comment: For some reason, that seems to hide the whole comments section, even on pages with a date...

Comment: This worked for me. I added it after the {/block:PostNotes} line and before the {block:IfDisqusShortname}. (your template may vary)